# Teradata: Case statement in analytical function

Tags: sql, teradata, analytical

I've a case where the data needs to be represented based on the events

[image: One month snapshot]

I need to achieve the following output

[image: Output]

Explanation:
ABC is represented thrice here and you can see date being different,

Initial Balance is the first_value of the ABC and the date combination.

Opening Balance is as of 01/12/2018

Closing Balance is as of 31/12/2018

Tried this sql but its throwing me Non-aggregate columns must be part of the associated group.

What wrong am doing and any insights on how to achieve the expected output.

```
select   
id||date as ID,
max(loanamt) over(partition by id,date order by strtdate) as Initial_balance
,max( case when strtdate = '2018-12-01' then balamt else 0 end ) over(partition by id,date order by strtdate ) as Opening_balance
,max(case when strtdate= '2018-12-31' then balamt else 0 end )  over(partition by id,date strtdate desc ) as Closing_balance
from tab
where id = 'ABC'
group by id;
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: You don't need the group by, you have only window functions. Or, you could use regular aggregation and group by `id||date`

Comment: Note that `date` is a legacy reserved word essentially equivalent to `CURRENT_DATE`. Either change that column name or put it in double quotes. Also the `id` in the GROUP BY clause resolves to the table column not the alias; it's not case-specific so either change the name or group by both source values or the expression or its ordinal number (GROUP BY 1). You likely do need both window functions and  GROUP BY, and nested queries / CTE since if window functions and aggregation are specified at the same level the aggregation happens first.

Comment: Don't use images for sample data / results when text or table formatting will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your data and narrative this should return the expected result:

```
select   
   id||date_col as ID
  ,loanamt as Initial_balance
  ,max(case when strtdate = DATE '2018-12-01' then balamt else 0 end) as Opening_balance
  ,max(case when strtdate = DATE '2018-12-31' then balamt else 0 end) as Closing_balance
from tab
where id = 'ABC'
group by 1,2;
```

Simple aggregation, no need for OVER.